# The integral of the Lie derivative over a divergence free vector field is zero

Tags: integration, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, lie-derivative, divergence-theorem

Let $M$ be a Riemannian manifold with metric $g$ and volume form $dV$. Let $L_X$ denote the Lie derivative taken over a vector field $X$. Suppose $X$ is a vector field over $M$ with compact support and $div(X) = 0$, where the divergence on a Riemannian manifold is defined as
$$d(X \lrcorner dV) = (div X) dV$$
where $\lrcorner$ denotes interior multiplication.

I would like to show that
$$\int L_Xf dV = 0$$
for all smooth functions $f$ over $M$.

My approach is to use Cartan's formula so that:
$$L_X f = X \lrcorner d(fdV) + d(X\lrcorner fdV) = d(X\lrcorner fdV) = (div X) fdV = 0.$$
Thus
$$\int_M L_Xf dV = \int_M 0 dV = 0.$$

The hint to this problem is to use the divergence theorem. Based on my work above I don't think is this necessary, is this correct? However if I were to use the divergence theorem, we have that
$$\int_m (div X)dV = \int_{\partial M} g(X,N) dV_{\tilde{g}}$$
where $N$ is the outward-pointing unit normal vector field along $\partial M$ and $\tilde{g}$ is the induced Riemannian metric on $\partial M$. I am new to Riemannian geometry and I am not sure how to compute the integral over the boundary where the integrand involves the metric on $M$. How would one compute this? How does this relate to the original integral containing the Lie derivative?

Comment: I don't trust your $d(\iota_X fdV) = (\operatorname{div} X) fdV$.

Comment: You are missing the wedge product in $dfdV$

Comment: Also, $L_Xf$ should be a function, and in your computations, you end up with a top-form.

Comment: @user10354138 I assumed this followed from the first formula/definition I gave but I think I see the problem now. That definition only applies to the canonical volume form, but $fdV$ is no longer a canonical volume form.

Comment: @Didier Thank you, that should be $d(fdV)$. I have corrected my post. For the second issue, can we interpret the $0$ form on the RHS as the 0 function?

Comment: @CBBAM What I meant is that the very first equality $L_Xf = X\lrcorner d(fdV) + \ldots$ already makes no sense: the LHS is a function, the RHS is a top form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Lie derivative of a function must be a function, not a top form.
Here are the right computations.
$\DeclareMathOperator{\Div}{div} \DeclareMathOperator{\lie}{\mathscr{L}} \DeclareMathOperator{\d}{d} \newcommand{\dx}{\d \!}$
\begin{align}
(\lie_Xf) \dx V
&= \lie_X(f\dx V) - f \lie_X\dx V & \text{by Leibniz rule}\\
&= X \lrcorner \d(f\dx V) + \d(X\lrcorner f\dx V) - f (\Div X) \dx V & \text{by Cartan's magic formula} \\
&= \d(X\lrcorner f\dx V)
\end{align}
the last equality being true since $f\dx V$ is a top form (hence $\d(f\dx V) = 0$) and $\Div X = 0$.
The result now follows from Stokes' formula.

Comment: Thank you very much! So we are not using the Riemannian divergence theorem at all?

Comment: @CBBAM The Riemannian divergence Theorem is nothing but Stokes' formula expressed in a fancy way, really

Comment: I see, I think this is what I have to study next as the equivalence between Stokes' theorem and the Riemannian divergence theorem isn't obvious to me.

Comment: @CBBAM The proof (that I know of) of the divergence Theorem is just saying that $L_XdV = div(X)dV$ by definition, plus that the induced volume form on $\partial M$ is $dV(\nu,-,\ldots,-)$ where $\nu$ is a unit normal, and finally applying Stokes' formula.

Comment: Thank you, I see the equivalence now.